# How to prove conjugate symmetry on an integral?

Tags: calculus

Seems strange that proving complex conjugate symmetry of integrals isn't discussed on here yet.

In general, how would you prove the conjugate symmetry aspect of an integral?

Comment: Can you write an equation that states what you mean by "the complex conjugate symmetry of integrals"?  Do you mean something like
$$
\int_a^b \bar f(x)\,dx = \overline{\int_a^b f(x)\,dx}?
$$

Comment: Yes, something like the proof of that would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you view $\Bbb C$ as $\Bbb R^2$, then conjugate is just sending $(x_1,x_2)$ to $(x_1,-x_2)$. The statement for integral follows from the fact that
$$\int^b_a -h(x)dx=-\int^b_a h(x)dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, what constitutes a "proof" here depends on your definition.  Assuming you define complex integrals via their Riemann sum, we have something like the following argument:

Let $f(x) = g(x) + ih(x)$ (where $g,h$ are real-valued) define a function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb C$.  We note that
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx =
\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N f(x_n^*) \Delta x_n =\\
\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N [g(x_n^*) + ih(x_n^*)] \Delta x_n = \\
\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N g(x_n^*) \Delta x_n +
i\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^N h(x_n^*) \Delta x_n =  \\
\int_a^b g(x)\,dx + i \int_a^b h(x)\,dx
$$
From there, the proof is easy.